# Multiple clickspans in a textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a function to build clickable tags for a textview. It goes as follows:

```
    private CharSequence tagsBuilder(String text, String token) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builtTags = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    int start = 0, end = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        start = 0;
        end = text.indexOf(token, 0);

        try {
            if(start < end) {
                SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text.substring(start, end));
                ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {

                        Log.i("DEBUGTAG", "Span clicked - " + ((TextView) v).getText());
                    }
                }, start, end, 0);

                builtTags.append(ssb);
                builtTags.append(" ");
                text = text.substring(end + 1);
            }
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return builtTags;
}
```

I can see the textview with 5 individually clickable tags. But the problem is, the Log that prints for any tag that is clicked is whole text of the textview.

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I get the text of individual tags that were clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log line is the following:

```
Log.i("DEBUGTAG", "Span clicked - " + ((TextView) v).getText());
```

That logs the contents of the `TextView`. So... you get the text of the `TextView`. If you want to get `token` in there, you'll have to copy that in.

Here's something you can try:

```
private CharSequence tagsBuilder(String text, final String token) {
SpannableStringBuilder builtTags = new SpannableStringBuilder();
int start = 0, end = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    start = 0;
    end = text.indexOf(token, 0);

    try {
        if(start < end) {
            SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text.substring(start, end));
            ssb.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                private String mText = token;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    Log.i("DEBUGTAG", "Span clicked - " + mText);
                }
            }, start, end, 0);

            builtTags.append(ssb);
            builtTags.append(" ");
            text = text.substring(end + 1);
        }
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        break;
    }
}

return builtTags;
}
```

Comment: My bad, I should have named the parameter appropriately. The token in the parameter is really a separator. Currently, "," is passed to break the comma separated strings into tokens.

Comment: Ah, right, I didn't read your code all that closely. Then just replace my use of `token` with the substring that you want. Your code looks off though, `start` is always 0...

Comment: Thanks much for help kabuko. I did not think deep into your original suggestion, but I get it now. It worked with a slight modification- final String mText = ssb.toString();

This code is a work in progress; I have optimized it to remove unwanted vars.